# Django KeyError kwargs.pop('pk')

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm using CBV in Django 1.9 and in CreateView when I try to pass an additional parameter ('pk') to my form using self.kwargs.pop('pk') i got "Key Error" but if I get the parameter by index it works, here is my code:

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None, **kwargs):
    self.project_version_pk = self.kwargs.pop('pk')
    form = super(HRCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['project_version'].queryset = form.fields['project_version'].queryset.filter(pk=self.project_version_pk)
    form.fields['project_version'].initial = self.project_version_pk
    return form

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(form=form)
```

And I get this error:

builtins.KeyError
KeyError: 'pk'

```
File "RelationView.py", line 65, in get_form

self.project_version_pk = self.kwargs.pop('pk')

KeyError: 'pk'
```

But if i read the key this way it works:

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None, **kwargs):
    self.project_version_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    form = super(HRCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['project_version'].queryset = form.fields['project_version'].queryset.filter(pk=self.project_version_pk)
    form.fields['project_version'].initial = self.project_version_pk
    return form
```

I don't really understand why the parameter is missing on pop() or which is the best practice for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't be overriding `get`. In a CreateView, Django already calls `get_form` for you - inside `get_context_data`. This is the cause of the issue you are having; you call `get_form` and pop the pk so that it is no longer in kwargs; but Django calls it again in get_context_data, but this second time it can't find the pk because you removed it the first time.

So don't use pop; but, as I said, don't do this at all. The only thing you actually need to override is `get_form`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response, but if i don't override get, how I could pass `'pk'` to `get_form` method?

Comment: You don't need to. You aren't using any of the arguments to that method anyway.

Comment: I'm passing the `'pk'` though this `form = self.get_form(form_class, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])` in `get` method, how form could get `'pk'` without have to be passed from other method? this because I have the same form for CreateView and UpdateView and I need to pass the `'pk'` only con CreateView. Sorry, maybe all this is obvious for you but I have been working with Django only few months, thanx in advance.

Comment: But `self.kwargs` isn't the same as the kwargs that are passed to the method; you're not using those at all.

Comment: How it's supposed I should pass the `'pk'` to `get_form` method?

Comment: For the third time, you don't need to. You are already referencing `self.kwargs` which is available everywhere.